# table cell that is only vertically scrollable

Tags: css, html

I am using the following CSS and bootstrap 3 to make a table cell vertically scrollable

```css
#scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table table table-condensed table-hover style="table-layout: fixed;" >
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="scrollable">something .................................long</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It appears to only scroll horizontally (just not in this snippet). I have tried to play with the above constraints, but no luck. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your text isn't long enough to trigger scrolling, because you haven't set a specific height (or width, if you want the text to wrap) on your table cell. Also, by setting the overflow on a `div` inside a `td`, you're making more work for yourself. Just set it on the `td` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow-y

```
#scrollable  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make your table body and table header to **display as block** then you try the overflow

check the below example...

```
<table>
<tableheader>
<tr>
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
    <th>Head 3</th>
    <th>Head 4</th>
    <th>Head 5</th>
</tr>
</tableheader>
<tablebody>
<tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
    <td>Content 4</td>
    <td>Content 5</td>
</tr>
</tablebody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tableheader, tablebody { display: block; }

tablebody {
    height: 100px;       
    overflow-y: auto;    
    overflow-x: hidden;  
}
```

if you need scrollbar in the cell which contains too large data please use the following in HTML table data tag

```
<td width="500" height="300">
 <div style="width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
 if the cell contains too large data it will appear the scrollbar
 </div>
</td>
```

Comment: but this only affects the table body. not the actual table cells. I don't want the table body to change. I only want to affect the individual table cells and make them scrollable when their contents are too large.

Comment: this is what i am doing currently. It gives me a horizontal scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

This Is Example For Your Question .

```
#scrollable  {
---------------
---------------
---------------
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```